# Nativescript google sign in (ios)

Tags: angular, nativescript, google-signin

In my nativescript-angular application I am trying to implemet sign in with google and the nativescript-social-login plugin. Trying to use the loginWithGoogle function exits the application (does not throw any error however)

Bellow you can see my code

**info.plist**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <!-- GOOGLE START -->
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <!-- GOOGLE END -->
</array>
```

**main.ts**

```
class MyDelegate extends UIResponder implements UIApplicationDelegate {
static ObjCProtocols = [UIApplicationDelegate];

applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions(application: UIApplication, launchOptions: any): boolean {
let gglDelegate = false;

try {
  const errorRef = new interop.Reference();
  GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(errorRef);

  const signIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance();
  gglDelegate = true;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

return gglDelegate;
}

applicationOpenURLSourceApplicationAnnotation(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation) {
const gglDelegate = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURLSourceApplicationAnnotation(url, sourceApplication, annotation);

return gglDelegate;
   }
}
application.ios.delegate = MyDelegate;
const google = {
initialize: true,
serverClientId: "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com", //this is from the ios id in my google console
isRequestAuthCode: true
 };
let result = SocialLogin.init({google});
 SocialLogin.addLogger((msg: any, tag: string) => {
    console.log(`[nativescript-social-login]: (+ ${tag} +): + ${msg}`);
 });
```

**login.component.ts**

```
googleLogin() {
try {
  SocialLogin.loginWithGoogle((result) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
              console.log("code: " + result.code);
              console.log("error: " + result.error);
              console.log("userToken: " + result.userToken);
              console.log("displayName: " + result.displayName);
              console.log("photo: " + result.photo);
              console.log("authToken: " + result.authToken);
          });
      });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(`[Error]: ${e}`);
  }
}
```

When i log the result from the .init function i get

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/main.js:49:12: {"facebook":{"isInitialized":true},"google":{"isInitialized":true},"twitter":{}}
```

Not quite sure where to go next...

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-social-login/issues/38#issuecomment-392036696 or if having trouble you could try an alternative login plugin `nativescript-plugin-firebase` which works excellent on my side

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I tried adding the hook and the entitlements file, as recommended by this link, but still the app exits when i tap on google sign in.
I will give firbase a try, but it a solution without firebase would be optimal for my case.